# Mobi site - mvc area or sub domain?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

About to start another jquery mobile site for an existing website. Cut down version of the main site offering limited functionality - not a mirror of the main site now in mobi format. Would be interested to get views on best route to take - mvc area or new mobi sub domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subdomain such as the typical "m.yourDomain.com";
on main site use if mobile 301 redirect to "m.yourDomain.com" and there will be less functional site and custom css code...  Both ways you suggest could work, different area of mvc too, it also depends on if you are doing something dynamic with your site like a cURL post where you should use same domain..  hope this gives insight.